# Java: Why passing an expression to System.out.print that results on a floating point number is printing 0?

Tags: java, printing, casting

I am executing this single Java line:

```
System.out.print(5/9*(0-32));
```

The result I am expecting is:

```
-17.77
```

But it is instead printing `0`.

It works if I do the following casting:

```
System.out.print((double)5/9*(0-32));
```

My question is: why do I need to do this casting? Moreover, shouldn't it print `17` if it is translating that expression to an int?

Comment: Without the cast to double, all the elements in your expression are integers, so the division is done according to the rules of integer division.

Comment: Just to make it clear: `5/9*(0-32)` does not result in a floating point number. As @NomadMaker says, it results in an `int`. On the other hand `(double)5` is a floating point number (same as `5.0`), so `(double)5/9*(0-32)` does result in a floating point number, a `double`.